# Python using lambda over 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, lambda

I have 2d array that's looking like this:

```
arr = [['l.p', 'WOJEWÓDZTWO', 'I KWARTAŁ', 'II KWARTAŁ', 'III KWARTAŁ', 'IV KWARTAŁ', 'ROK'], ['1', 'DOLNOŚLĄSKIE', '44051', '58780', '72099', '49849', '224779'], ['2', 'KUJAWSKO-POMORSKIE', '27606', '35075', '43219', '29388', '135288'], ['3', 'LUBELSKIE', '25398', '31477', '40618', '28247', '125740'], ['4', 'LUBUSKIE', '14311', '18441', '24097', '16666', '73515'], ['5', 'ŁÓDZKIE', '33422', '41741', '48932', '34732', '158827'], ['6', 'MAŁOPOLSKIE', '46007', '61539', '80323', '51869', '239738'], ['7', 'MAZOWIECKIE', '83344', '107440', '128938', '90005', '409727'], ['8', 'OPOLSKIE', '12579', '17905', '23521', '15084', '69089'], ['9', 'PODKARPACKIE', '25061', '32480', '45521', '28423', '131485'], ['10', 'PODLASKIE', '14696', '17973', '25828', '16053', '74550'], ['11', 'POMORSKIE', '35294', '45188', '58568', '38965', '178015'], ['12', 'ŚLĄSKIE', '65433', '87470', '103829', '70947', '327679'], ['13', 'ŚWIĘTOKRZYSKIE', '15194', '18453', '24460', '17069', '75176'], ['14', 'WARMIŃSKO-MAZURSKIE', '18262', '22988', '30881', '20396', '92527'], ['15', 'WIELKOPOLSKIE', '46560', '60833', '74028', '52963', '234384'], ['16', 'ZACHODNIOPOMORSKIE', '24907', '31569', '41878', '27725', '126079']]
```

I am trying to convert all numeric strings to a integer, with something like this:

```
new_arr = list(map(lambda x: list(filter(lambda y: (int(y) if y.isnumeric() is True else str(y)), x)), arr))
```

Can someone expaling why it doesn't work?

Comment: Any of numeric elements of first array doesn't change to integer

Comment: What do you think `filter` does? Why do you expect it to convert anything? Did you mean `map` instead of `filter`?

Comment: Oh, I see it right now i misleaded filter with map function. Now it's working thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your current code is that it uses filter instead of map when applying the lambda you defined. I think what is happening is that the function is either returning a string or a number based on the if statement you created, but filter is then simply using that output to determine whether to keep the element in the list or not. Since Python treats all non-zero ints and all non-empty strings as "truthy", this just means it returns the same list. Here is a corrected version of your code which works:

```
new_arr = list(map(lambda x: list(map(lambda y: (int(y) if y.isnumeric() else str(y)), x)), arr))
```

In case you're interested, here is another way of doing it with a list comprehension:

```
new_arr = [[int(x) if x.isnumeric() else x for x in l] for l in arr]
```